# flutter show images (assets) in rapid succession

Tags: flutter

Part of my Flutter app has a filter function which filters through a list of items. This being part of a UX should indicate the current operation to the user.

**The issue** I am facing is displaying the current item being filtered (evaluated) - the images simply won't be displayed or will "get stuck" on 1 - reason most likely being the run loop set the state too fast for the redraw to take place.

Here is a rough example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int i = 0;
  List<String> _images = [
    "assets/sample/sample1.jpg",
    "assets/sample/sample2.jpg",
    "assets/sample/sample3.jpg",
    "assets/sample/sample4.jpg",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(), () {
      while (true) {
        i++;
        setState(() {
          i = i % 4;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget content = Container(
        child: ClipRRect(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 24,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Image.asset(_images[i], gaplessPlayback: true,),
      ),
    ));

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: content,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Question:**

To simplify things, how can I display a few images rapidly (and repeatedly) i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3... with a few milliseconds delay between (at most)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use while loop because it will block the thread and does not let other tasks be executed

you could use something like Timer.periodic and it gives you the option to control the frame rate that images should change

and also don't use setState because it causes the entire widget to rebuilt you can use ValueNotifer to notify the specific widget direct with changes

and also remember to cancel the timer when your widget gets disposed

here is example

```
class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  ValueNotifier<String> currentImage = ValueNotifier("0.png");
  int counter=0;
  Timer imageTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.imageTimer=Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      counter++;
      currentImage.value="${counter%3}.png";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
      valueListenable: currentImage,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Image.asset(
          value,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if(imageTimer!=null)imageTimer.cancel();
  }
}
```